# How to trigger search of a smartfield value help programmatically?

Tags: sapui5

if i open the value help dialog of a smartfield, i need to press "Go" / "Start"-Button to get some elements in the value list. Is it possible to trigger the "Go"-Button programmatically or trigger the search function with an empty search string after pressing the value help icon?

Comment: If you don't like the "Go" button you can try setting `liveMode` to `true` on the smart filter bar

Comment: SmartFilterBar is not accessible. It is generated automatically through SmartField annotations

Answer (score 1):

There is a smart field configuration property 'preventInitialDataFetchInValueHelpDialog' which controls whether data should be fetch initially when the value help dialog is opened or not. The default value of this is 'true' and if you set this to false, the data will be fetched on opening the value help. Here is the working example:

```
<smartField:SmartField value="{Material}" change="onChangeMaterial">
  <smartField:configuration>
    <smartField:Configuration preventInitialDataFetchInValueHelpDialog="false" />
  </smartField:configuration>
</smartField:SmartField>
```

More details are here: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.comp.smartfield.Configuration